# How to fill out the last row with fake items in a responsive flexbox grid layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

We have the typical responsive flexbox grid with fixed-width elements, and a dynamic number of rows, based on screen resolution and the number of items. For example, say we have seven `<div>`s, it will show something like this:

[image]

We need to complete the last row with "fake" items, or placeholders, with no extra HTML:

[image]

And, if we change the resolution, it should recalculate the needed placeholders:

[image]

Is this even possible with just plain CSS?

We're using flexbox, but we're open to using CSS Grid layout if it solves our problem.

Comment: Please include your code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Not really, can be done without JS.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes We don't have nothing to show, we're just thinking if it's possible to solve it with plain CSS. We have the first case, of course, but it's just a list of divs within a flexbox container.

Comment: Please can you include that as it would be better than nothing and give a starting point for any changes.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Code is only required for "why doesn't this code work" debugging questions. Questions asking how to do something from scratch (or asking if something is possible) do not require code; they just uncommon because most are too broad. This one isn't, however.

Comment: @TylerH Fair enough, although giving the code that they had up to that point would have provided a good jumping off point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be an approach.

The trick is to use pseudo-elements (acting as placeholders) to replicate every item in the same position a row below. And use `overflow: hidden` to hide the last row of pseudo-elements that fall outside the flex container. Here's a pic showing a `3px` displacement and the overflow, to help understanding the idea.

[image: The trick]

But, of course, it might have many flaws depending on your specific requirements.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #299CFF;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  color: white;
}

li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(3em + 2 * 0.25em);
  content: "X";
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
  <li>32</li>
  <li>33</li>
  <li>34</li>
  <li>35</li>
  <li>36</li>
  <li>37</li>
  <li>38</li>
  <li>39</li>
  <li>40</li>
  <li>41</li>
  <li>42</li>
  <li>43</li>
  <li>44</li>
  <li>45</li>
  <li>46</li>
  <li>47</li>
  <li>48</li>
  <li>49</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great, but with this approach you need to know the number of columns of the grid, which we don't, because we need it to be responsive. Our problem is more like "ok, we have 12 100px-width items. Just build the grid in the available space and complete the last row with the fake elements".

Comment: Not exactly. This is responsive. For illustrative purposes, I fixed the width of the `wide` and `narrow` containers, but just take a look at the pen: https://codepen.io/jordinebot/pen/qKEdbw

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've look closer to what you're doing here, and I understand it now. Brilliant!

Comment: Just to get the whole answer right: what'd you do if the incomplete (and only) row was the first one? The "duplicate and displace" approach wouldn't be enough. Any suggestion?

Comment: In this case, I would place the pseudo-elements to the right, instead of below, but you should calculate the distance to cover at least the number of actual items you have to be sure you fill the whole container. And that would only work if you have at least half row filled.

Comment: Honestly I would remove the first snippet and stick with the 2nd, it's much better as an answer to this question. Or at least minimize the first and expand the 2nd.